# Partition Problems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm new when it comes to Ubuntu.
So I created a 200gb partition for me to install Ubuntu on and store stuff from Ubuntu.

[image: partition diagram]

After I boot into Ubuntu I get to the part where I select the drive I wish to install on. I see all my drives, but not the free space I created, yet the free space shows up a 1MB.

Comment: You created not "free space" but a NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

Get a better partitioning tool for windows like `MiniTool Partition Wizard`or even better use `GParted` from Live Ubuntu USB to see the partitions. Be careful while performing actions in `GParted`. Refer [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).